# Changing text color in a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

There's a method for altering background color but not font.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. The WebView just displays the HTML you give it so you would just use normal HTML/CSS to modify the content displayed within.

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to do that w/o modifying the underlying html.

Comment: Is the underlying HTML something from a third party? You could always inject javascript at the end that will modify it and then call the javascript from the Activity itself doing wvMyWebView.loadUrl("call javascript function here");

Comment: @MattC what if you change the app theme and you want to see changes instantly.

Answer (score 40):

something like

```
String text = "<html><head>"
          + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #fff; background-color: #000;}"
          + "</style></head>"
          + "<body>"                          
          + your_string_text_here
          + "</body></html>";

webview1.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 25):

I had to put it in the onPageFinished method.

```
_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        _webView.loadUrl(
            "javascript:document.body.style.setProperty(\"color\", \"white\");"
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: partially work, some of the font color still not overwritten

Comment: @BeeingJk that is because the font is overridden by the site

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(
        "javascript:document.body.style.setProperty(\"color\", \"white\");"
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: With recent changes in this area, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#webview-color-theme, I wish there was a way to accomplish this without enabling JavaScript and trigger static code analysis warnings

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest way I found (change the text color to white for example):

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.color=\"white\";");
```

Comment: how to change the font type

Comment: note that you will have to enable javascript for the web view in question, otherwise the call will have no effect

Answer (score 2):

When the buffer is SPANNABLE, modifying the HTML directly is an ideal solution. The font, color, typeface, style can all be affected through HTML:

```
String szMessage = "<font face='trebuchet' size=30><a href=zz><b>click me</b></a></font>";

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(szMessage), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

@rafraph's answer didn't work for me. I had to use

```java
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.setProperty(\"color\", \"white\");");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your answer one body tag HTML with CSS style hex color, this is an example using a JSON response

First: function for decode JSON to HTML format

```
public String stripHtml(String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```

Second: Load data in WebView (no url)

```
 String string_html;
 string_html = "&lt;body style=&quot;color:#535362;&quot;&gt;" + youStringHTML + "&lt;/body&gt;";
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, stripHtml(string_html), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```