# On WebView long click highlight the selected text in Android

Tags: android

I have loaded a local HTML file from assets folder into `WebView.Also` On `WebView` long click its open a custom dialog box. This is my code:

```
 pageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            String names[] ={"Copy","Bookmark","Note"};
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            final AlertDialog ad=alertDialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now I want to add bookmark functionality on selected text. How is it possible?

Comment: are you loading a website or a custom content?

Comment: custom html file from assets.

Comment: you can check this maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/37645059/6689101

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it at all But you can try below solution.

For that you have to add custom css style in your html file as below :

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
}
```

here it will disable highlight color of selected text.
Try it out and let me know Is it working or not?