# Change text colour inside WebView in Android

Tags: android, html

I would like to change the text colour of text inside html file to white colour as I have changed the background colour to black. How can I achieve this?

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: check the link looks similar ask, hope it helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254970/changing-text-color-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to update directly the content displayed in a webview by a webview method. The only way to update the text color is to update the content of page1.html in your case.
Webview role is only to display an html content, not to update it.

Comment: so there is no possible way to do it?

Comment: You have some solutions : have different html files and get the good one with the color you want dynamically, write the html content in a string and use it in the webview with loadData methods and somes others.

Comment: So in a nutshell, use different html for different text colours?

Comment: It could be a solution. it's not the best because you will duplicate the html files.

Comment: Yeh that's what I'm trying to avoid and it wouldn't be good if I have alot html files to begin with 

Comment: For sure. But it's clearly impossible to update the color of the html content with the WebView. WebView role is unique and is to display a web content. That's all. It's not responsible to create or update the content.

Comment: ok sure, thanks for the advice